# Heroku Django Static

Tags: django, heroku

Do static images expire after soon point and automatically get deleted?

My situation is that I retrieve images from my PostgreSQL database through a model's ImageField by setting its `upload_to` equal to `static/images`. Then, I access the images through `mysitesurl.com/static/images/model.url` This works perfectly initially. However, after several hours, what I notice is that the images are no longer accessible. When I try to access them through the same url, they no longer exist. I do not do any manual image deletions so the operations I perform should not interfere with this.

Is this something that Heroku does that I do not understand?

Also, one odd occurrence that I notice is that the image is still accessible through the url, but it doesn't actually get saved to `static/images`. At least, when I run `heroku run ls static/images`, it is not there. Is this the correct way to check a directory's contents in heroku?

EDIT: My configs

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
    'static/uploaded_stuff/',
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `heroku run bash --app YOUR_APP` from your repository directory. This creates a shell to your Heroku instance allowing you to navigate around your files.

You can check on your static images that way.

I would suggest using S3 to serve your static images though. You can view this tutorial on how to integrate it:
http://blog.doismellburning.co.uk/2012/07/14/using-amazon-s3-to-host-your-django-static-files/

After further details, you are trying to allow user uploads and Heroku's file system is read-only. You will need to use S3 or a similar hosting solution for static/uploaded files.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Comment: thank you for your reply :), but for personal reasons, I'm trying not to host it on S3 and am looking for a solution to only using heroku to serve static files. I'm just not sure why the images are only temporarily available.

Comment: Are you seeing the images in the folder via the heroku bash?

Comment: Unfortunately, my images are not there. However if I navigate to the url 'mysitehere/static/uploaded_stuff/019.JPG', I can see that the image right when I upload it. However, when I look at the directory 'static' through bash, the uploaded_stuff directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you post your settings.py entries relating to `STATIC` and also your entire folder structure of where your static files are located?

Comment: my tree structure looks like 'app --> static --> css folder, js folder, and uploaded_stuff folder' . However, none of the static files originally in the project have an issues. It's only the user-submitted images that disappear after sometime. Also, I edited my original pose with settings.

Comment: I also ran across this statement after much searching "Cedar filesystem was ephemeral, i.e. wiped whenever the dyno is restarted" ; might this be the cause? However, I don't believe so because my image never gets uploaded to the static file in the first place. In my local development server this produces no issues.

Comment: You're losing me now with the only the "user-submitted" images not being found. You never mentioned this before. How are these being submitted, where are they being saved, etc. Please give as much as information as possible.

Comment: Oops so sorry wasn't sure if that was relevant, but I have a form that takes in an image. The image is then passed to a model's ImageField (mentioned in original post). So, a user can submit images through an upload button. The upload_to field is set to my static folder so that I do not have to manually provide url visibility to the images. So, after initial upload, the image is visible. However, after a few hours, the images are no longer accessible and during this entire time bash shows no images in my static folder. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: These details were very important as you cannot write to Heroku's file system via the application - if you are seeing the images, it must be through some sort of cache. You will need to use S3 or a similar hosting solution in this case. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem